# file_put_contents(result.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, json

I was trying to generate a .JSON file in PHP for use in Android. I am getting the following error:

> file_put_contents(result.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied on line 18.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'conn.php';
$name = array();//array created to store the data.
$sql="SELECT * FROM employee_data;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)  or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
}
$jsonarray = json_encode(array('output'=>$output));
echo $jsonarray;
//Take special care of the msqli and the sql queries

//creates the file
$fileName = 'result'.'.json';
if (file_put_contents($fileName, $jsonarray)) {
    echo $jsonarray." is created";
}else{
    echo "There is some error";
}
?>
```

Thanks For Help:)

Comment: Not sure what more we can add to the error message - whichever system user is running the PHP script (www-data, etc) doesn't have permission to write that file to the working directory

Comment: nothing to do with android tag i believe

Comment: question does not relate to Android. Removing `android` tag

Comment: you are trying to write in folder you dont have permission to write in it...your post in wrong tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    require 'conn.php';

$name = array();//array created to store the data.
$sql="SELECT * FROM employee_data;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)  or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
}
$jsonarray = json_encode(array('output'=>$output));
echo $jsonarray;
//Take special care of the msqli and the sql queries

//creates the file
$fileName = 'result.json';
if (file_put_contents($fileName, $jsonarray)) {
    echo $jsonarray." is created";
}else{
    echo "There is some error";
}
?>
```

Issue is in your $fileName.
Please check the above code.
I hope it helps.